# Android Studio takes too long (35 minutes) to run a project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to run my project on android studio and it takes 35 minutes to run
I am using Gradle to compile and message is gradle build running.

I have used

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

I also tried the `gradle mode offline` but still the same issue

Comment: Add your Gradle file(s)

Comment: ... outdated hardware?

Comment: no its new configration it works perfect while i run it in Admin login

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware might be outdated, Android studio takes a lot of resources to run, upgrade to an ssd and you should be fine

Comment: its not a hardware issue i have checked everything is perfect when i run in Admin login

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in other answers it could be that your hardware is not capable of handling the resource requests made by android studio. But, also check the following:

make sure you are using the right `buildToolsVersion` in your app's `build.gradle`. It should match the `targetSdkVersion`.

Additionally, try switching to the latest API Level i.e. `targetSdkVersion 23` and use `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` and see if that makes things better.

**Update after your comment below:** Like you mentioned the time is very high only under your login. And it takes far less time under admin login. Try and stop all background heavy processes under your login. Those may be consuming a lot of resources making less available for android studio to use.

Comment: i used it and its same. i have run my project with Admin login and it takes only 2-3 minute but with my login it takes 30 minutes . do you have any idea about any help will be appreciated.

Comment: in that case there are background processes running in your login that are taking up resources. kill/stop those.

Comment: i am using eclipse for my server side code . in same pc and maven to run it . is it make any diffrence?

Comment: i see in process where two java is running in same time

Comment: yes it makes a lot of difference. Eclipse id a devil when it comes to consuming resources. Close eclipse and try

Comment: i have kill process and close eclipse still it takes same time.